# How to change the default schemalocation in wsdl file of WCf Service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Following is the wsdl file of my service:

```
    <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:3789/VideoUpload.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:3789/VideoUpload.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:3789/VideoUpload.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UploadVideoProtocol" /> 
      </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
-----
<wsdl:definitions>
<wsdl:service name="VideoUpload">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IVideoUpload" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IVideoUpload">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:3789/VideoUpload.svc" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In the above, I could change the namespace by specifying the custom namespace inside the code in service contract and behavior.

But I need to change the endpoint address specified in the schema location,

**schemaLocation="http://localhost:3789/VideoUpload.svc?xsd=xsd0"**

To my own defined endpoint address as:

**schemaLocation="http://myservice.com:8080/VideoUpload.svc?xsd=xsd0"**

What is the procedure to achieve this? what has to be mentioned in the code to change the default endpoint generated? Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You have to change httpGetUrl. Check out these posts. http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/domain-name-replaced-with-machine-name.html
http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/wsdl-service-soap-address-location.html

Comment: hey thanks... works great. but when i assigned a domain name instead the ip address i couldnt access. how to use the same with a domain name instead specifying an ip address?

Comment: It should work, as dns resolves ip address and send request to specific IP, make sure about configuration settings

Comment: configuration settings of web config or IIS?  I have changed the host header of the that particular service hosted on IIS as some domain(www.yourdomain.com). i have mentioned the same in httpGetUrl as http:\\www.yourdomain.com:8080/VideoUpload.svc?. but it doesn't work. May i know what are all the settings has to e changed in IIS? can u pls help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically update the WCF endpoint address in the WSDL meta data by adding a new behavior that implements "IWsdlExportExtension"

```
public class HostNameAddressBehavior : Attribute, IWsdlExportExtension, IEndpointBehavior, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter,
        WsdlContractConversionContext context)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overwrite service meta data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exporter"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
    {
        var address = "YOUR_ENDPOINT";

        context.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(address);

        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = exporter.GeneratedXmlSchemas;

        foreach (System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription wsdl in exporter.GeneratedWsdlDocuments)
        {
            foreach (XmlSchema schema in wsdl.Types.Schemas)
            {
                ChangeSchemaLocation(schemaSet, schema, address);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update XSD location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlSchemaSet"></param>
    /// <param name="xsdDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="address"></param>
    private void ChangeSchemaLocation(XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemaSet, XmlSchema xsdDoc, string address)
    {
        foreach (XmlSchemaExternal external in xsdDoc.Includes)
        {
            if ((external != null) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(external.SchemaLocation))
            {
                string str = (external is XmlSchemaImport) ? ((XmlSchemaImport)external).Namespace : xsdDoc.TargetNamespace;
                foreach (XmlSchema schema in xmlSchemaSet.Schemas(str ?? string.Empty))
                {
                    if (schema != xsdDoc)
                    {
                        external.SchemaLocation = address + "/?xsd=xsd0"; // set the location;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add your new behavior by code or in the config file.

By code:

```
var endpoint = listener.ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints.First();
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new HostNameAddressBehavior());
```

OR

By Config:

Create extension:

```
    public class HostNameAddressBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(HostNameAddressBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new HostNameAddressBehavior();
    }
}
```

Then add:

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="hostNameAddress" type="YourService.HostNameAddressBehaviorExtension, YourService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
```